# Determine numpy dtype from list

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a better way to infer the numpy dtype for a list `l` than `np.array(l).dtype`? [pandas.api.types.infer_dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.infer_dtype.html) comes close but it returns a string instead of a `np.dtype`.

Comment: A list doesn't have a dtype.  What you show is the dtype of the array created from the list.  The details of that inference depend on the elements of the list - and that can be simple or complex if the list contains a mix of elements.

Comment: I know all that, I'm asking if there is a public function that exposes what `np.array()` does internally to determine the type, without having to create a temp array.